# Add grid to GetFeatureInfo tool

Tags: geoext, boundless-suite, getfeatureinfo, sdk

I have added the GetFeatureInfo Tool to my Viewer but the PopUp does not have a grid in it to display the Feature Info neatly.

How do I get the grid layout in the Feature Info PopUp, like the one that we are able to see in the popup box in the feature edit tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default format of the WMSGetFeatureInfo plugin is html, which leverages server side templates for the output. If you want the grid format, you have to configure the plugin with the 'format' option set to 'grid':

```
{
    ptype: 'gxp_wmsgetfeatureinfo',
    format: 'grid'
}
```

See http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/sdk-api/lib/plugins/WMSGetFeatureInfo.html for the full documentation of the WMSGetFeatureInfo plugin.